# How to have multiple versions of Jenkinsfile through git tags?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So, I am able to deploy a code by using a specific git tag and the build is picking the accurate commit as per that git tag. That is perfectly working, however, the same build is always picking only the latest commit for Jenkinsfile. Is there any way I can make Jenkins pick the Jenkinsfile from a specific commit as well?

Here's my checkout method:

```
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "refs/tags/${env.tag}"]],
        extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, shallow: false, depth: 0, reference: '']],
        userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
      ])
```

Comment: What type of job?  Have you tried things like disabling the 'lightweight checkout' option, or using the `skipDefaultCheckout()` option?

Comment: Yep, I did disable the Default checkout method. I haven't checked the 'lighweight checkout' thing, will check that now. It's a declarative pipeline job